# Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-oauth, pug

JS file config is

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export async function postLogin  (req, res, next) {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const auth = getAuth();   
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
     .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
     })
     .catch((err)=>console.log('ERROR : ' + err));
}
```

And a pug file with a button triggers the "postLogin" function.
The result is error
Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment)

I read lots of documents and blogs, unfortunately not solve the case.
Many documents are react based. But I don't use react. Is that any solution?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow steps at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

> Before you begin
> Add Firebase to your JavaScript project.
> Enable Google as a sign-in method in the Firebase console:
> In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
> On the Sign in method tab, enable the Google sign-in method and click Save.

Comment: Yes, I had followed those steps. I did.

Comment: I can write , delete, etc to database. But google sign in not working. Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment)